# 'str' object has no attribute 'paste'

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm working on code that takes different images and overlays them. I got this code online and I'm trying to change it to work what I wanna do, but when I run it, i get this:

Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'str' object has no attribute 'paste'

I'm new to python so I'm struggling to figure out what's wrong with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import random
import os

from PIL import Image

#overlaying
background.paste(jacket, (0,0), mask = jacket)
background.show()
```

`background` variable code:

```
background_path = r"C:/Users/cspea/Desktop/background/"
background = random.choice([
    x for x in os.listdir(background_path)
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(background_path,x))
])
```

`jacket` variable code:

```
jacket_path = r"C:/Users/cspea/Desktop/jackets/"
jacket = random.choice([
    x for x in os.listdir(jacket_path)
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(jacket_path,x))
])
```

*I'm only pasting part of the code that I need help with out of concern for security. All variables in the code above work perfectly fine. When I run the program without the code above, it runs flawlessly.*

Comment: Where are you defining `background` ?

Comment: @PedroMaia Just updated the question with the information

Comment: `background` and `jacket` are simply strings holding a pathname.  You need to load those files into PIL `Image`s to do anything with them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that background is not an image yet.  you need to do something like the following.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter

background_img = Image.open(background)
jacket_img = Image.open(jacket)

background_img.paste(jacket_img, (0,0), mask = jacket_img)
background_img.show()
```